# Update MYSQL Table from multiple rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to update **table yy** from **table xx** results by doing sum.

For example (syntax is abstract):

```
update table_yy
  set sum_of_x_and_y = (
       (select sum(row_x) from table_xx where class_id=1)
                 +
       (select sum(row_y) from table_xx where class_id=1) )
```

**Table xx**

```
row_id   class_id   row_x   row_y
   1        1        4        5
   2        1        5        6
   3        2        6        7
   4        1        7        8
```

**Table yy**

```
class_id   sum_of_x_and_y
   1            35
   2            13
```

but instead of setting the class_id manually, I would love to do something like inner-join update, but I'm working with 15k+ of records.

Comment: Don't practise on the live data. You really need a test database where you can try things out without fear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query that should do the job

```
UPDATE table_yy, (
    SELECT class_id, SUM(table_xx.row_x + table_xx.row_y) AS sum_of_x_and_y
    FROM table_xx
    GROUP BY table_xx.class_id 
) AS table_sum
SET table_yy.sum_of_x_and_y = table_sum.sum_of_x_and_y
WHERE table_yy.class_id = table_sum.class_id
```

Comment: Oh wow! you are amazing thank you! the secret all along was "GROUP BY", I just realized that you can do mathematical operations while you group up results!! Thank you , you just taught me something new <3

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine.  You just want a correlated subquery:

```
update table_yy yy
    set sum_of_x_and_y = (select sum(xx.row_x) + sum(xx.row_y)
                          from table_xx xx
                          where xx.class_id = yy.class_id
                         );
```

Under many circumstances, this will have better performance, particularly if you have an index on `table_xx(class_id)`.